# Jquery to Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

How do I convert the jquery code below to prototype?

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready (function() {
        $("#valor").keyup(function(){
            var resultVal = 0.0;
            var objRegExp = '\s+';
            $("#valor").each ( function() {
                resultVal += parseFloat ( $j(this).val().replace(/\s/g,'').replace(',','.'));
            });
            $("#total").val(resultVal);  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: if can show that you tried, you will get a higher response rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, but pure JavaScript is always nice:

```
function doLoad() {
     var valor = document.getElementById("valor");
     valor.onkeyup = function() {
          var resultVal = 0.0;
          var objRegExp = '\s+';
          for(var i = 0; i < valor.childNodes.length; i++) {
               var n = valor.childNodes[i];
               if(n.nodeType === 1) resultVal += parseFloat(n.value.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
          }
          document.getElementById("total").value = resultVal.toString();
     };
}

if(window.addEventListener)
     window.addEventListener("load", doLoad, false);
else
     window.attachEvent("onload", doLoad);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example with the migration:

http://jsfiddle.net/MaQA5/

### Code:

```
eventObserver = function() {
    var resultVal = 0.0;
    var objRegExp = '\s+';
    $$(".valor").each(function(el) {
        resultVal += parseFloat($(el).getValue().replace(/\s/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
    });
    $("total").setValue(resultVal);
};

$$('.valor').each(function(el) {
    el.observe('keyup', eventObserver);
});
```

### Some comments:

From your code, I supposed you have several inputs with the same `id` (`valor`). If this is the case, that's wrong, as ids must be unique in the whole DOM.

That's why I changed that for a `class` named `valor`.

Prototype has a special `$$` function to get elements by css-selector. But uses `$` for id search or to turn a DOM element into a Prototype-empowered element.

When calling to `each` method, instead of using `this` as every element in the original collection (like you do in jQuery), you must use the first argument in the function: `el`.

Instead of calling the `keyup` jQuery method, you must use `observe('keyup', ...`.

In my opinion, jQuery is more elegant, or at least, the Prototype that I know is not that fancy :)

Comment: I also personally prefer the jquery simplicity. However, I had conflict with a prototype plug-in. Thank you for your help and comments.